# There's no main.xml in /res/layout

Tags: android

I've started reading "Building your first app" in developer.android.com.
When they start creating different UI, they refer you to /res/layout/main.xml file.
But I can't find it - under /res/layout There's only activity_first.xml file ( My activity'
s name is FirstActivity ).

I've read that it might be because of API16, but I get the same problem with API15.

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

I use Eclipse 3.7.2 ( Indigo ) On Linux Debian, if it matters

Comment: y don't u create it then

Comment: I think it should be generated automatically, so maybe the guide is just outdated and things have changed... better ask than start doing things on my own without knowing what I should do...

Comment: @Niv can you please link me to the page on `developer.android.com` you mentioned?

Comment: @Sanjay http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: @Niv : **better ask than start doing things on my own without knowing what I should do** - Good idea but as you start to become familiar with Android, you'll realise that you will need to create many XML layout files each with unique names. As long as you reference the correct layout for what you need then it doesn't matter what you call the files. Example...`setContentView(R.layout.fruit)` simply needs to have a layout file `fruit.xml` which has a valid layout. Similarly `R.layout.cars` or `R.layout.login` just need valid `cars.xml` and `login.xml` layout files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In new `ADT 20` ,there are `activity_main` if your Activity name is
>   `MainActivity`

i think `activity_first.xml is your main.xml.`.see in your Activity have `setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);`

Comment: It actually does, but the activity_first.xml doesn't look like the described main.xml - They show a code that contains <LinearLayout>, while activity_first.xml contains only <RelativeLayout>

Comment: As you might have realized, I'm a complete newbie, so I don't know what that means. Well, I know what the ADT is, but not how it affects/what should I do about it.